# need to return multiple array any datatype

Tags: angular, reactjs, ecmascript-6

`var a = ["A", "|" , "B" ,"|", [],"|",{obj:"Ashut"},"|",["ashu"]];`

I need the output like this:

```
A | B | [] | {obj:"Ashut"} | ["ashu"]
```

I tried like this:

`a.reduce(function(item, index){
    return item + index;
});`

but didnot get the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
a.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    if (typeof cur === 'object') {
        return prev + JSON.stringify(cur);
    } else {
        return prev + cur;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
// Input array
var a = ["A", "|" , "B" ,"|", [],"|",{obj:"Ashut"},"|",["ashu"]];

// convert objects into string
var b = a.map((item) => {
 if (typeof item === 'object') {
   item = JSON.stringify(item);
  }
  return item;
});

// join the array
var res = b.join(' ');

// result
console.log(res);
```